# Gray bar caused by NavigationController at bottom of screen

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my iPad app, I'm using a `UITabBarController`, with some of the tabs being a `UISplitViewController`. I've noticed when I embed my split views into a Nav controller I end up with a gray bar that spans the bottom of my screen that I cannot get rid of it.

For example, this:

[image: Storyboard with one embedded Nav controller]

Produces this:

[image: Gray bar example]

Now, if I go in and embed the detail side into a nav controller, here's the result:

[image: 2nd Example]

I've tried everything I can think of and that gray bar at the bottom just won't go away. Anyone have any tips?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Subclass `UISplitViewController` and add:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
}
```

or

```
- (BOOL)extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars
{
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars property of the UISplitViewController to true.  This can be done when you initialize the controller (most likely in AppDelegate).  I didn't need to subclass UISplitViewController to get it to work. Tested with iOS 9.2 and 9.3.

```
let splitViewController = UISplitViewController()    
splitViewController.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
```

Comment: Is this the same as what [Bear with me](http://stackoverflow.com/users/348796/bear-with-me) suggests in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24808923/3982001)? Or is it different? It looks very similar. Can you please [edit] your post and explain the difference? Thank you!

Comment: Sure.  Only difference was not having to make the subclass.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a SplitViewController with **Navigation controller** each **ViewController** or **TableViewController** in the ViewDidLoad add:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = YES;
}
```